# "public://public://user-pictures does not exist" when trying to change user profile photo path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to change the path for the user profile pictures in a Drupal 7 installation and I'm getting the following error:

> The directory public://public://user-pictures does not exist or is not
>   writable.

The path that I'm entering is simply "user-profiles".

I tried resetting the variable stored in the database by using the value from a new installation:

```
 UPDATE variable 
 SET value=0x733A313A2231223B 
 WHERE name = 'user_pictures';
```

The update was successful but the problem remained.

Does anybody know how to correct this or where this value is stored in the database?

Thanks

Comment: I've documented this issue and pointed at the root cause bug report here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2509188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_pictures` is a boolean variable, you're probably looking for `user_picture_path`.

Since variable values are stored in serialised PHP arrays it'll be much easier to update that path using the API:

```
variable_set('user_picture_path', 'user-profiles');
```

Comment: The other reason to use `variable_set()` is that Drupal caches the variable values. With `variable_set()`, the cache is cleared, while that doesn't happen when an SQL query is used. In the latter case, Drupal is still using the cached value until a module doesn't call `variable_set()`.

Comment: Where would I add this code, I am having the same type of problem

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Clive answer, you can use drush from the command line :

```
drush vset user_picture_path your_path
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and am able to solve the issue.

“*public://public://user-pictures does not exist” when trying to change user profile photo path.*"

What is did: Navigated to **mysite.com/admin/config/people/accounts**
 in '**Picture directory**' field default value was 'pictures', i have changed the directory name to my custom directory name 'prof_images' and now when i try to save the settings, i started getting the above error. I have cross checked the Directory name and permission but everything was fine.

How i solved the issue:
Navigated to Drupal core modules folder **/modules/user** and commented the following lines:

> Blockquote

if (!file_prepare_directory($picture_path, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
      form_set_error('user_picture_path', t('The directory %directory does not exist or is not writable.', array('%directory' => $picture_path)));
      watchdog('file system', 'The directory %directory does not exist or is not writable.', array('%directory' => $picture_path), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    }

> Blockquote

After clearing the cache, everything went cool.
Navigated to mysite.com/admin/config/people/accounts and set 'prof_images' as my user image directory and saved the settings. This time my settings are saved without any problem.

Then uncommented the above lines in the user module and everything worked as usual.

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks

Comment: Hacking core, even temporarily, is never a good solution. https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core